# Leer archivo.txt en c++ (Me repite el ultimo registro)

Tags: c++, archivo, fstream

Necesito de su ayuda, quiero leer un archivo de texto en c++, en el que solo estoy mostrando los nombres, el problema es que me repite el ultimo, el codigo es tan sencillo que no se que tengo mal

```
 //Leer las tablas
string texto;
string nom;
string aux;
int cont = 0;
    ifstream lectura;
    lectura.open("Tablas.txt",ios::in);
    if(lectura.fail()){
        cout<<"No se pudo abrir el archivo";
        exit(1);
    }
cout<<endl;
cout<<"Los nombres de las tablas existentes son: "<<endl;
    while(!lectura.eof()){
    lectura>>nom>>aux;
    cout<<nom<<endl;
    }
    lectura.close();
```